# Spring Boot Web project set up in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I am new to Spring Web development.  Basically, I need to know how to run the Spring project in Eclipse IDE.  Here are the detailed steps I have perfoormed so far, with pics/code to support my question.

1. I visited Spring Initializr site and downloaded a maven project folder. I endered the following information:
   Project:  Maven Project
   Language:  Java
   Spring Boot:  3.0.0 (SNAPSHOT)
   ProjectMetadata - Group: com.example
   ProjectMetadata - Artifact: demo10
   ProjectMetadata - Name: SpringTest
   Dependencies:
   Spring Web - Build web, including RESTful, applications using Spring MVC. Uses Apache Tomcat as the default embedded container.
2. I imported the downloaded file into Eclipse as Existing Maven Project.  (Eclipse Version  2021-12(4.22.0)
3. Created the following class was created by spring initializer

```
package com.example.demo10;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringTestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

4. I created the following controller class

```
package com.example.demo10;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public  class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String getWelcome() {
        System.out.println("test");
        return "we are fome";
    }
}
```

5. [Here is the project file structure in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06tzO.png)
6. Here is the pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo10</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringTest</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

So following are my two questions:
a.  From this point how do I run the project on Tomcat server.  I already have two versions of Tomcat installed.
b.  What is the url I should use to call the api?

Thanks

Comment: use this https://start.spring.io/  and no need to worry about the rest of things

Answer (score 0):

as you said,  Uses Apache Tomcat as the default embedded container. you can run your project when you identify @SpringBootApplication annotation in your main class

Spring boot use url that is localhost::8080 as a default.Also, you can change it using application properties files for example "server.port = 9999" and your url will be localhost::9999

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I have modified the body of querry a bit.  I have already identified the  @SpringBootApplication annotation in your main class.

Still, I am not sure how to run the project from this point

Comment: You run the class containing the `public static void main` method as a Java Application, because that is what it is.

Comment: Thanks @hsymuls.  I now understand how to run the application